# Building a query optimization

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm doing this in my code:

```
programmes2 = [int(l) for l in g.getlist('programmes2')]
if len(programmes2):
    q = q & Q(personne__programmes2__in=programmes2)

activites2 = [int(l) for l in g.getlist('activites2')]
if len(activites2):
    q = q & Q(personne__activites2__in=activites2)

hobbies2 = [int(l) for l in g.getlist('hobbies2')]
if len(hobbies2):
    q = q & Q(personne__hobbies2__in=hobbies2)

types_permis2 = [int(l) for l in g.getlist('types_permis2')]
if len(types_permis2):
    q = q & Q(personne__types_permis2__in=types_permis2)

personnalites2 = [int(l) for l in g.getlist('personnalites2')]
if len(personnalites2):
    q = q & Q(personne__personnalites2__in=personnalites2)

langues2 = [int(l) for l in g.getlist('langues2')]
if len(langues2):
    q = q & Q(personne__langues2__in=langues2)
```

I was wondering if it was possible to transform this into something like:

```
for i in ['hobbies2', 'types_permis2', 'and so on']:
    q = q & Q(personne__i__in=i)  # obviously wrong, not working
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure:

```
q = Q()
for field in ["hobbies2", "types_permis2", "and so on"]:
    values = [int(l) for l in g.getlist(field)]

    if values:        
        field_query = "personne__{}__in".format(field)
        q = q & Q(field_query=values)
```

Here's another approach:

```
fields = ["hobbies2", "types_permis2", "and so on"]
params = {"personne__{}__in".format(field): [int(l) for l in g.getlist(field)]
          for field in fields
          if g.getlist(field)}

result = MyModel.objects.filter(**params)
```

Comment: Perfect! You made my day!